# Stochastic Integral Help

Tags: stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

Let W(t) be a Brownian Motion.

Show that the integral:
$$
\int_t^T W(s)ds
$$

can be written in terms of the stochastic integral:

$$
\int_t^T (T-s)dW(S)
$$

Is there an error with this question? I can only show that it can be written as:

$$
\int_0^T (T-s)dW(S)
$$

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Itô's formula,
$$
\mathrm d(W(s)s)=W(s)\,\mathrm ds+s\,\mathrm dW(s),
$$
so integrating between $t$ and $T$ yields
$$
T\,W(T)-t\,W(t)=\int_t^TW(s)\,\mathrm ds+\int_t^Ts\,\mathrm dW(s), 
$$
whereby
$$
\int_t^TW(s)\,\mathrm ds=T\int_t^T\,\mathrm dW(s)+(T-t)W(t)-\int_t^Ts\,\mathrm dW(s)
=(T-t)W(t)+\int_t^T(T-s)\,\mathrm dW(s).
$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is what I am getting too, so this suggests an error in the question formulation?

Comment: Technically, this expression is "in terms of" $\int_t^T(T-s)\,\mathrm dW(s)$. There is also the possibility that I made a mistake.

Comment: Oh, fair enough, I was trying to show that the two were equivalent, that makes sense though, thanks a lot!